# Celcius, Kelvin, or Newton to Fahreinheit calculator

Tags: c++

I am attempting to make a calculator that will take in a value in Celsius, Kelvin, or Newtons and output the degrees in fahreinheit. The assignment limitations are below..

I have been working on this assignment for the past three days and can not make any headway past this point. One pervasive error is this "cin is not an overload function" error.. Has me totally baffled!

"Required:

You are not allowed to use a do-while loop for this program.

Use a while loop in conjunction with a switch statement. Please review the information on primed loops.

You must prime your loop with input from the keyboard before the while loop starts.

The program should continue converting temperatures until X is entered as a conversion type.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int C;
int N;
int K;
char decision;
char DegreeUnit;
int Temperature;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++);// i <100 just for the sake of testing if the loop will work..)

if(tolower(DegreeUnit!='x'))// I want it to lower a capital 'x' so there's no error.. If they put in 'x' program SHOULD terminate..)
{
cout << "What would you like to convert from? And what is the temperatue in that unit?(Press X to exit)" << endl;

cin >> DegreeUnit; // This is where they should put an answer in the following format C 32
cin >> Temperature;

{
    if(DegreeUnit=C) // These if statements are where the maths should occur..

cout << Temperature*(1.8)+32  << endl;
}
{
    if (DegreeUnit=N)

cout <<(Temperature*60)/(11)+32 << endl;
}
{
    if (DegreeUnit=K)

cout << (Temperature-273.15)*1.8 +32 << endl;
}
}// loop here and return to "What would you like to convert from?"

return 0;
}
```

f there is anything I am doing wrong (Which I probably am) please let me know..

Comment: You have a semicolon after the for loop. What is the problem you are having? Also you should compile with warnings turned on. (For instance you also have assignment in if statements.)

Comment: I see you have DegreeUnit=C instead of with single quotes: DegreeUnit=='C'
Also you have a semicolon at the end of your for loop.  You probably want a curly brace such that it'll loop over the code a number of times.

Comment: Let yourself know. Compile your program; if there are errors, then there is something you are doing wrong (and the compiler will do its best to tell you what that something is). Then, test your program, verify that it runs correctly and produces correct results. If it does not, then there is something you are doing wrong. If your program runs correctly and produces enough correct results to give you confidence, then it is likely that you have done nothing wrong. Testing is an important and necessary skill.

Comment: @Fdinoff, I have not been able to get the program to run.. Dang! With those two comments I think it is working fully now!

Comment: @user  I did not know I had to do DegreeUnit=='C'.. If it's not too much trouble, could you explain why that is?

Comment: @JuliusVerne search for what is the difference between = and == in c++, then search for comparing strings and you will have half of your code fixed and you will understand half of what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Julius Because `DegreeUnit=C` assigns the variable DegreeUnit to the value of a variable named C, which isn't what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Had an extra semicolon and needed to change DegreeUnit=C to DegreeUnit=='C' (as well as the other DegreeUnit if statements..)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int C;
int N;
int K;
char decision;
char DegreeUnit;
int Temperature;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)// i <100 just for the sake of testing if the loop will work..)
{
if(tolower(DegreeUnit!='x'))// I want it to lower a capital 'x' so there's no error.. If they put in 'x' program SHOULD terminate..)
{
cout << "What would you like to convert from? And what is the temperatue in that unit?(Press X to exit)" << endl;

cin >> DegreeUnit; // This is where they should put an answer in the following format C 32
cin >> Temperature;

{
    if(DegreeUnit=='C') // These if statements are where the maths should occur..

cout << Temperature*(1.8)+32  << endl;
}
{
    if (DegreeUnit=='N')

cout <<(Temperature*60)/(11)+32 << endl;
}
{
    if (DegreeUnit=='K')

cout << (Temperature-273.15)*1.8 +32 << endl;
}
}// loop here and return to "What would you like to convert from?"
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should read the assignment requirements again.  There's no while, no switch, and no priming the loop.  `tolower(DegreeUnit!='x')` is also incorrect, you may have meant `tolower(DegreeUnit) != 'x'`

Comment: I forgot about priming the loop..Couldn't I just copy and paste the loop text outside the loop, allow it to run once, then enter the loop?